# Should -Throw Method in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, pester

I am trying to run some test in PowerShell that will check if the version in SolutionInfo.cs file is correctly formatted, is it missing or is it okay.

With my tests I am trying to cover those scenarios. One of them for checking the file, when the version is okay, is passing but the rest is failing. In addition I am sending you the script and the tests. The solution files contain version. Can someone please help me with these two cases and how the `throw` method or any other that is fit for my case should look like?

```
function Get-VersionFromSolutionInfoFile($path) {
    try {
        [Version]$version = (Get-Content -Raw $path) -replace '(?s).*\bAssemblyVersion\("(.*?)"\).*', '$1'        
    } 
    catch {    
        throw "Missing version or incorrect format."
    }
    return $version.ToString()
}

it "returns version from SolutionInfo.cs file"{
    Get-VersionFromSolutionInfoFile("$pwd/SolutionInfo.cs")  | Should -Be '1.0.0.0'
}
it "returns exception if there aren't any versions in the file"{
    Get-VersionFromSolutionInfoFile("$pwd/SolutionInfo2.cs")  | Should -Throw 
}
    it "returns exception if the version is not in the correct format"{
    Get-VersionFromSolutionInfoFile("$pwd/SolutionInfo3.cs")  | Should -Throw
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `Should -Throw` you need to provide a scriptblock as input, so your tests need to be as follows:

```
it "returns exception if there aren't any versions in the file"{
    { Get-VersionFromSolutionInfoFile("$pwd/SolutionInfo2.cs") }  | Should -Throw 
}
    it "returns exception if the version is not in the correct format"{
    { Get-VersionFromSolutionInfoFile("$pwd/SolutionInfo3.cs") }  | Should -Throw
}
```

You should also add `-ErrorAction Stop` to your `Get-Content`. This ensures that your `Catch` is triggered, as it forces the exception to be terminating:

```
function Get-VersionFromSolutionInfoFile($path) {
    try {
        [Version]$version = (Get-Content -Raw $path -ErrorAction Stop) -replace '(?s).*\bAssemblyVersion\("(.*?)"\).*', '$1'        
    } 
    catch {    
        throw "Missing version or incorrect format."
    }
    return $version.ToString()
}
```